# Before build: Will this circuit work, or have I overlooked something?

Tags: power-electronics, wiring, speakers, bad-wiring

Some friends and I have given ourselves the goal of building a unidirectional speaker. We bought the necessary components and electronic parts.

Before starting to connect everything we wanted an opinion from someone who knows a little more about it to validate our wiring diagram.

[image: wiring diagram]
<sub>[Circuit source.](https://github.com/gururise/directional_speaker)</sub>

Here is our wiring diagram:

[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: that blue thing with the circles needs to be rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: Description says "unidirectional speaker" (whatever that is?). Schematic is labeled "Ultrasonic Lazer" (whatever that is?). Please provide more insight as to what you are trying to do as otherwise it is difficult to critique your circuit.

Comment: Always give specs that can be verified before design to ensure it works as expected!  Same here for review.

Comment: A comment as it's not a thorough review, but I'd change how you've connected the unused opamp section U1B, see this note from TI https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204a/sboa204a.pdf

Comment: Do you think that prototype breadboards automatically change from horizontal to vertical internal connections based on the wires you have plugged into them?

Comment: The 4427 and the ultrasonic module need *serious* power supply decoupling.

Comment: The long wires all over the place and rows of contacts on the solderless breadboard are antennas that will pickup mains hum and all kinds of interference. The lousy old LM358 has trouble with frequencies higher than about 4kHz and produces lots of hiss and distortion.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your wiring diagram doesn't show the [MIC4427](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC4426-7-8-Dual-1-5A-Peak-Low-Side-MOSFET-DRivers-DS20006202A.pdf)
2. In the wiring diagram, all the pins on what appears to be an ultrasonic sensor are shorted together.
3. Your schematic shows an STM32 BluePill while your wiring diagram shows an Arduino Due.
4. The LM358 in your wiring diagram doesn't seem to have a ground or a power connection.
5. The schematic has an audio connector going to the LM358.  The signal then goes to an analog input on the processor.  The wiring diagram shows a microphone module going directly to the Arduino Due and the LM358 just sort of hanging around with half of its pins disconnected.

The wiring diagram is barely related to the schematic.

You have many problems to deal with, starting with how breadboards are wired.

Have a look at [how breadboards are wired.](http://wiring.org.co/learning/tutorials/breadboard/)

This diagram from the linked page says most of what you need to know about breadboard wiring:

[image]

The biggest (and probably hardest part) of whatever that circuit does is incorporated in the software of the processor.  Once you get the wiring sorted out, you'll have to see about translating the software from the BluePill to the Arduino Due.

Answer (score 0):

View this image in conjunction with JRE's answer.

You have connection errors in the areas marked.

[image]